# Осуществлять доступ?

Tags: словообразование

Скажите, пожалуйста, насколько правильна фраза «осуществлять доступ» (в помещения, например). На мой взгляд, слегка коряво. А ваше мнение?

Answer (score 3):

Доступ (куда-либо) - в условном смысле, категория **мнимая**. Это возможность (напр. техническая или правовая) попасть куда-либо или приблизиться к чему-либо (у него есть доступ туда-то). Воспользоваться этой возможностью - значит, мнимое перенести в **материальную** область, т.е. "**осуществить**" его. Соответственно, это выражение корректно, хотя и имеет ограниченное применение.

Так чаще говорят о других мнимых категориях: замысле, мечте, праве и т.п. Поэтому вне контекста словосочетание "осуществить доступ" может показаться непривычным или излишне канцелярским. Оно больше встречается в техническом (компьютерном) смысле, когда имеющий доступ (право или техн. возможность доступа) к чему-либо в сети пользователь "осуществляет" этот доступ сложной последовательностью действий. В быту можно себе представить, напр. *осуществление доступа в помещение* с банковскими ячейками, что может быть связано со сложными техническими процедурами. Воспользовавшись банковской картой, её владелец *осуществляет доступ* (как право и техническую возможность) к своему счёту.